# Upload File with BootstrapVue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, bootstrap-vue

anyone knows how to submit file with bootstrapVue file input?
I am getting null from request->all()

```
array:13 [
 ...
  "calibration_cert" => array:1 [
    "$path" => null
  ]
]
```

Below is what I tried

```
            <b-form-group label="Calibration Cert:">
                <b-form-file
                    v-model="form.calibration_cert"
                    :state="Boolean(form.calibration_cert)"
                    placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
                    drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
                ></b-form-file>
            </b-form-group>
.....
      methods:{
        onSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            axios
                .post("/equipments/create", this.form, {
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                })
            };
        },
```

Appreciate if anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lucky day, I'm just working on this.

- You have to use `formData()` object for submitting files from Axios.
- If your Laravel route uses a `patch` method, you have to use `axios.post()` instead of `axios.patch()` and append the `_method: PATCH` in your `formData`

Saying that, this is how I do it:

component.vue

```
<b-form-file
    v-model="form.calibration_cert"
    :state="Boolean(form.calibration_cert)"
    placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
    drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
></b-form-file>

.....

methods:{
  onSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      // Set formData
      const formData = new FormData()
      // Append the method only if you are using a patch route in your server side
      formData.append('_method', 'PATCH')
      // Append the file
      formData.append('calibration_cert', this.form.calibration_cert)
      // Append the rest of your form data
      formData.append('data1', this.form.data1)
      formData.append('data2', this.form.data2)
      .....

      axios
         .post("/equipments/create", formData, {
              headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
              }
          })
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
          })
      };
},
```

Then in your Laravel side, you can do

```
$path = $request->file('calibration_cert')->store('files');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the files as a object in axios request, use below example to understand what you should do.

```
const app = new Vue({
    data: () => ({images: null}),
    template: `
      <div>
        <input type="file" @change="uploadFile" ref="file">
        <button @click="submitFile">Upload!</button>
      </div>
    `,
    methods: {
      uploadFile() {
        this.Images = this.$refs.file.files[0];
      },
      submitFile() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.Images);
        const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' };
        axios.post('https://httpbin.org/post', formData, { headers }).then((res) => {
          res.data.files; // binary representation of the file
          res.status; // HTTP status
        });
      }
    }
  });

app.$mount("#content");
```